# How to limit one value to appear at most once in a column in Postgresql?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql

How do I add a constraint or a unique index to `position` column in a Staff entity so that the value `master` can appear at most once while other values can appear however many times?

Is it even possible?

I am using Postgres database, Ruby on Rails and `schema.rb`.

Comment: Have you considered validating on the model level?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure postgres enforces that kind of constraint. An alternative solution would be to set a custom validation on the model along the lines of

```
class SomeModel
  validate :one_master_permitted

  private
  def one_master_permitted
    errors.add(:position, "some error message") if SomeModel.find_by(position: "master")
  end
end
```

Comment: You have mismatch between `:only_one_master` and `def one_master_permitted`.